# Security Validation error while executing Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal command

Tags: error, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am executing the below PnP Powershell command to get the App Principals registered in the SPO Site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "SiteURL" -TenantAdminUrl "TenantAdminSiteURL" -UseWebLogin
Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal -scope Site -IncludeSubsites
```

But I get the below error: What I am doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: This error looks to me of cache issue of login. Can you try simple `Connect-PnPOnline` with your attribute in different window, to try out? I had same error with SharePoint in browser but then I cleared cache and relogin solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved once I used -Interactive instead on -UseWebLogin. Below script worked for me:

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "SiteURL" -TenantAdminUrl "TenantAdminSiteURL" -Interactive
Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal -scope Site -IncludeSubsites